# Is the following phrase correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to know if this phrase is correct: "Go be a postmodernist somewhere else".

Comment: It is alright (in America at least). In Britain the imperative form "go be" is not an accepted collocation. We would always put a conjunction in between the two words, such as "Go and be a postmodernist" or "Go but be careful". Don't forget that a sentence needs to start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least in American English. For several attested examples of similar phrasings in published literature, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Go+be+a+*+somewhere+else%22&btnG=Search&num=100&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks).

(They include

*Go be a dragon man somewhere else. 

Go be a bummer somewhere else.  

You can go be a dog somewhere else.  

Hey, man, go be a nuisance somewhere else.*)